Angular: NG01001 and NG01002 errors in Sentry but not in browser console
I am encountering two specific errors, NG01001 and NG01002, in Sentry when running my Angular application. However, these errors do not appear in the browser console, and the application seems to work fine in the browser.
Errors:
Error: NG01001
Error: NG01002
Angular Version: 16.2.12
Question:
What could be causing these errors to appear in Sentry but not in the browser console?
How can I resolve these errors or prevent them from being reported in Sentry?
